# Not able to print a variable/hash in a test case with Test::WWW::Mechanize::Catalyst in perl catalyst app

Tags: perl, testing, catalyst

I am writing test cases for a Perl Catalyst based web application with Test::WWW::Mechanize::Catalyst. I stuck somewhere and I want to troubleshoot by printing a variable/hash value. But the problem is that it just show the console log of Catalyst App. How can I print a variable value in console? like in catalyst $c->log->info($variable value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your tests with `prove` you need to add the `-v` flag to see all the test output.

```
$ prove -v t/
```

That way it will not eat up all the TAP output.

You can then use [`diag` from Test::More](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::More#Diagnostics) to output comments into the TAP, or [the `warn` builtin](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html).

```
use Test::More;

pass 'first test';
diag 'this is a diagnostical message';

my $res = pass 'another test';
warn $res;

done_testing;
```

That produces this output (on Windows):

```
$ prove -v foo.pl
foo.pl .. # this is a diagnostical message

1 at foo.pl line 7.
ok 1 - first test
ok 2 - another test
1..2
ok
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=2,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr +  0.02 sys =  0.03 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

However, what I usually do is to use [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer)'s `p` function, which also writes to STDERR like a warning. It's a bit more powerful than Data::Dumper and displays objects nicely. The debug output from `p` will also just end up somewhere in the TAP.

It can get confusing if there is a lot of logging from the application going on, so turning off the Catalyst log is an option. To do that, run your tests with the environment variable `CATALYST_DEBUG` set to `0`.

```
$ CATALYST_DEBUG=0 prove -v t/
```

If instead you want your debug output *from the test* go into the Catalyst log, you need to grab a context. That's a bit more tricky, but possible.

```
use Test::More
use Test::WWW::Mechanize::Catalyst;
use Catalyst::Test 'MyApp';
use Data::Printer;

my $mech = Test::WWW::Mechanize::Catalyst->new(catalyst_app => 'MyApp');

$mech->get_ok("/");

my($res, $c) = ctx_request('/');
$c->log->warn(np $res); # this will go to the Catalyst log
```

That code uses both [Test::WWW::Mechanize::Catalyst](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::WWW::Mechanize::Catalyst) and [Catalyst::Test](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Test). If you pass the same app name they won't get into each other's way and the app will only be started once.

I'm showing a regular mech test with `get_ok` and the `ctx_request` function from Catalyst::Test. It returns an HTTP::Response object and the context `$c` from that request. You can run `->log` on the context and your debugging will go to the Catalyst log. I'm using `np` from Data::Printer, which returns the debugging info generated by Data::Printer instead of writing it to STDOUT so I can put it into the Catalyst log.

Comment: I don't have access to a Catalyst right now. I'll revise this once I do.

Comment: Glad this helped you @Amid. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. See [ask] how to do that.

Comment: Hi simbabque, can I use this ctx_request with post_ok see the below code, I am getting the error.  $ua1->post_ok("/corp/product/$branchid",
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',  Content => $product_add_json ) or BAIL_OUT  Dumper $ua1->response;
 my($res, $c) = ctx_request("/corp/product/$branchid");
                $c->log->info( np $res, "response output is"); I am getting error Can't locate object method "np" via package "HTTP::Headers" at /usr/share/perl5/HTTP/Message.pm line 644. while I installed Data::Printer package and included it.

Comment: @AmitBondwal put parenthesis after the `np` call. Perl gets confused and thinks you are doing indirect object notation. Make it `$c->log->info(np($res))` and get rid of that other text. If you want two lines of log, call `$c->log->info()` twice.